# query multiple entities in Google Datastore with a clean syntax

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using node.js with Google App Engine for a class project. My code works fine so I'm not asking how to solve this, but this is ugly beyond reason and I'm assuming there has to be a better way for making this look clean. That isn't part of my grade, just want to know the better way. Also less round trips is always desired so

I have built a basic forum backend but part of creating a forum thread is I need to check that the thread has a unique name and that the user exists. Plan on adding authentication later, but for now just querying the name.

Is there a way to use a single query to get 2 entities by key if they are of different 'kinds'? Nesting queries like this seems bad all around. Not finding a lot of documentation on this subject, or my google-fu is a bit weak. Do something like this in a couple places so would really like to improve on this in particular.

Basic code

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {

    if (req.body["Name"] == null || typeof req.body["Name"] !== "string")
    {
        res.json({ success: false, data: "Name was not a valid string." });
        return;
    }

    if (req.body["Creator"] == null || typeof req.body["Creator"] !== "string")
    {
        res.json({ success: false, data: "Invalid creator submitted for thread creation." });
        return;
    }

    //See if thread is unique
    var query = datastore.createQuery('Thread')
        .filter('__key__', '=', datastore.key(['Thread', req.body["Name"]]));

    datastore.runQuery(query, function (err, entities, nextQuery) {

        //
        if (err == null && entities.length == 0) {

            var query2 = datastore.createQuery('User')
                .filter('__key__', '=', datastore.key(['User', req.body["Creator"]]));

            datastore.runQuery(query2, function (err2, entities2, nextQuery) {

                if (err2 == null && entities2.length >= 1)
                {
                    var threadKey =
                        {
                            name: req.body["Name"],
                            kind: "Thread",
                            path: ["Thread", req.body["Name"]]
                        }

                    var threadData =
                        {
                            Creator: req.body["Creator"],
                            DateCreated: new Date(),
                            LastUpdated: new Date()
                        }

                    datastore.upsert({
                        key: threadKey,
                        data: threadData
                    }, function (err) {

                        if (err) {
                            res.json({ success: false, data: "Was unable to add value to datastore for unknown reason." });
                            return;
                        }
                        else {
                            res.json({ success: true, data: "Was able to add thread to datastore." });
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    res.json({ success: false, data: "Cannot create thread because a valid user was not submitted." });
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            res.json({ success: false, data: "Cannot create thread because a matching name already exists." });
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since queries are on a `Kind`, you cannot run a single query across `Kind`s.  However, if one `Kind` is an ancestor of the other, then a single query can get both.  For example, if `creator` were a property of `Thread`, as the `User` who created it, then a query on the thread can also contain properties of the creator.

More at: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#ancestor_paths

Comment: This is true, but since I'm running such a simple query of getting a key a transaction or multi-get will work fine I found out. So true, but for places you know the keys already you can go across Kinds by not using queries which works if you don't need filters.